# How to interpret custom AND OR Condition

Tags: apex

I have a parent and child object. Child object stores the condition and parent record stores the conditions with AND OR logic. How can I use this condition in IF block in program.

[image]

```
public class ruleEngine {
    public void ruleMethod(){
        for(Survey_Rule__c rule : [Select Id, Name, Condition__c, (SELECT Name, Object_Name__c,Field_Name__c,Value__c from Survey_Conditions__r)from Survey_Rule__c]){
            rule.Condition__c = rule.Condition__c.toUpperCase();
            for(Survey_Condition__c condition : rule.Survey_Conditions__r ){
                //Account Field Name
                condition.Field_Name__c = condition.Field_Name__c.replace('Customer Type', 'Type__c');
                
                String ruleStr = condition.Object_Name__c + '.' + condition.Field_Name__c + ' = \'' + condition.Value__c + '\'';
                
                rule.Condition__c = rule.Condition__c.replace(condition.Name, ruleStr);
            }  
            rule.Condition__c = rule.Condition__c.replace('OR', '||').replace('AND', '&&');
            system.debug('rule.Condition__c: ' + rule.Condition__c);
        }
        
    }
}
```

Debug log

```
System.debug: 18:49:21:086 USER_DEBUG [15]|DEBUG|rule.Condition__c: Account.Type__c = 'Leaser' || (Case.Type = 'ABC' && Contact.Name = 'Test Contact')
```

**I want to use this string as IF condition.**

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce does not provide us the ability to do this, which I would probably describe as meta-programming (writing code which writes other code).

You could cause this runtime-generated code to be executed via a callout to your org's execute anonymous endpoint, but callouts are slow and have restrictions (when you can make a callout, how many you can make, etc...)

Beyond that, you'd be looking at needing to build your own expression evaluator in Apex, which I assure you is no easy task (and far beyond the scope of this question, and even this site).

Your best move here is to re-evaluate the requirements here, and you/your boss/your company pushing back *hard* to avoid needing to do this.